# SFTP mget and get command to copy multiple folders or files to one server directory

Tags: sftp

I needed to copy multiple folders of same directory using one command. So I did this first,

`sftp> mget -r folder1 folder2`

This command copied `folder1` to the destination server but renamed it to `folder2`.

I probably should have done something like the following. But, I did not try it

`sftp> get -r folder1 && sleep 5 && get -r folder2`

I did not try this but I think it would have worked.

Is there any better alternative to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mget` subcommand in sftp is [an alias to `get`](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/sftp.c?rev=1.186&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup):

```
static const struct CMD cmds[] = {
    { "bye",    I_QUIT,     NOARGS  },
    ...
    { "get",    I_GET,      REMOTE  },
    { "mget",   I_GET,      REMOTE  },
    ...
};
```

The [`get` subcommand](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp) has a syntax of:

> ```
>  get [-afPpr] remote-path [local-path]
> ```

If you give `get` or `mget` multiple parameters, it treats the second one as the rename destination for the first. As a result, you cannot retrieve multiple directories at once; you'll need to get them separately:

```
mget -r folder1 
mget -r folder2
```

The sftp syntax also does not allow for shell-style command chaining, so you cannot use a command like: <strike>`get -r folder1 && ...`</strike>. There is also no need to try and `sleep` between get commands, unless you need a delay for other purposes (a watching process locally, to spare the network for a few seconds, etc).

As an alternative to `sftp`, consider `scp`:

```
scp -r user@host:folder1 user@host:folder2 /local/directory
```

... which will recursively copy the *remote* `folder1` and `folder2` directories into the *local* `/local/directory`.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I copied both folders separately in the end. I tried scp command but it did not work for me, so get command was the only option for me.

Comment: @RakibFiha, consider the syntax for `scp` that I just added to my answer as another possibility.

Answer (score 4):

If your folders are folder1 and folder2, you can get them using one command.

```
get -r folder[1-2]
```

> get [-afPpr] remote-path [local-path]
>   Retrieve the remote-path and store it on the local machine. If the local path name is not specified, it is given the same name it has on the remote machine.  remote-path may contain **glob(7)** characters and may match multiple files.  If it does and local-path is specified, then local-path must specify a directory.